# Generate an IP address with family other than IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to make sure my code doesn't accept string IP values in formats other than IPv4 and IPv6. I have something like this:

```
if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out var parsedIpAddress))
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}

if (parsedIpAddress.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork
    && parsedIpAddress.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Only IPv4 and IPv6 formats are supported.");
}
```

This is fine, but to unit test this, I'm trying to generate an IPAddress object where `AddressFamily` is anything other than `InterNetwork` or `InterNetworkV6`. I looked at the `System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily` enum and tried to look up an example of an address that'd match some of the other values in there, but no matter what string I provide to `IPAddress.TryParse()`, it either returns false OR parses it into an `InterNetwork` or `InterNetworkV6`. I looked at definition of `.TryParse()` and it ends up calling [IPAddressParser.Parse()](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/release/6.0/src/libraries/System.Net.Primitives/src/System/Net/IPAddressParser.cs), which only seems to support IPv4 and IPv6. It seems like it's practically impossible to parse values other than these two - is my understanding correct? Is there a point in checking the address family in the first place then?

Comment: What other kind of IP address there could be? To your last question, the library supports IPv4 and IPv6, there is no mention in any other type (and I don't know any other type), so no, it doesn't make sense to check the family in your case.

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily is what I'm referring to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.addressfamily?view=net-7.0.

Comment: It's not practically impossible, it is in fact impossible. `IPAddress.TryParse` will attempt to parse the address as IPv6, and if that doesn't work, will parse it as IPv4. It will never return any of the other address families. Most of these are for obsolete technologies; they're included because Winsock/Berkeley sockets include them, but the .NET libraries have no explicit support for them. They can still be used in `Socket` and addresses for them could be constructed through the `IPAddress` constructor that takes a `byte[]`, but they have no string representations supported by .NET.